# codeigniter folder structure on webserver

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to upload code igniter folder to remote server. Should I upload codeigniter root folder to my public_html folder so I got following structure

```
public_html/
            codeigniter/
                       application/
                       system/
                       ....
```

or should I upload application system ... directly to my `public_html`, 
and if I upload under codeigniter folder can I point somewhere in config to my codeigniter library in a way that my links remains without `/codeigniter/`

Comment: If you do it your way, you will access the website as www.yoururl.com/codeigniter

Comment: @RaduCojocaru it will depend on the apache configuration

Comment: better to upload it to the public_html/ directly

Comment: True, I was thinking of the default configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's better to do like:

```
application/
system/
public_html/
    index.php
```

for security reason, put your `application` and `system` folder outside your `public_html`

Comment: you say that I should put ci folder content outside of public_html? Where in config should I point to ci library?

Comment: In index.php change the path to the system & application folder to be one level up from public_html/index.php.

Comment: You can access your CI library as usual, what you need is just set right path to your `system` and `app` folder like @stefandoorn said.

Answer (score 3):

Form the user guide

> For the best security, both the system and any application folders
>   should be placed above web root so that they are not directly
>   accessible via a browser.

So my setup is to have a custom **`public`** directory in the codeigniter codebase and have the **`index.php`** inside it.

And copy the **`.htaccess`** and **`index.html`** from either **`system`** or **`application`** folder to the codebase to forbid access to the base.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the apache configuration on your server.

From my POV, it is better to have a structure like :

```
public_html/
codeigniter/
    application/
    system/
    [...]/
```

Then, make your apache configuration point to this folder with something like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "path_to_the_folder/codeigniter"
    ServerName yourDomain.loc
    ServerAlias www.yourDomain.loc
    <Directory path_to_the_folder/codeigniter/ >
        #Your options
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and your `/etc/hosts` file look like :

```
127.0.0.1    yourDomain.loc
127.0.0.1    www.yourDomain.loc
```

Answer (score -2):

You would typically upload everything under /codeigniter. So you would have a directory structure like:

```
- public_html
  - images
  - js
  - system
    - application
    - other codeigniter folders
```

Comment: Preferably put the system & application folder outside public_html.